# Sublime Text regex with optional groups

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

Example Data (including newlines)

```
Alpha1
100
Bravo2
something else
Charlie3
200
Delta4
A==1
Echo5
300
Foxtrot6
```

I would like to get the output of:

```
Alpha1 100 Bravo2 something else
Charlie3 200 Delta4 A==1
Echo5 300 Foxtrot6
```

The pattern is:

```
AlphaNumeric
Numeric
AlphaNumeric
value that is not a single alphanumeric "word"
```

The first three parts are easy -- `(\w+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\w+)\s+` -- but I don't know how to have the conditional fourth group.  Is this possible?  If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This pattern worked for me:

```
(\w+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\w+)(\s+([\w\s]+ \w+$))?
```

Before:
[image: Before]

After:
[image: After]

Of course, `\w` includes underscores, so replace `\w` with `[a-z0-9]` if necessary.

**Update**

This pattern is more specific and should be more reliable:

```
(\w+)\n(\d+)\n(\w+)(\n([^\n]*[^\w\n][^\n]*))?
```

Before:
[image: Before]

After:
[image: After]

Comment: I added a line of sample data where I was lacking:  A single "word" that contains punctuation is also valid as the optional fourth.